# How to redirect localhost to 127.0.0.1:8080?

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost

Due to unidentified problem, any service pid4 is using port 80 of my Windows 7-64 bit PC's. I ultimately decided to change my default port to 8080. But how can I change the way that when I enter localhost in URL, then automatically the data from 127.0.0.1:8080 comes.

I also edited the hosts file as

```
127.0.0.1:8080 localhost
```

but it didn't work. Please help me someone.

Comment: On what OS? If it's linux use iptables. But I would tend to identify the uniedentified problem, though.

Comment: It helps if you explain what the problem is rather than starting with a suggested solution. Why do you need to do this? What issue do you expect this to solve?

Comment: The 'unidentified problem' could be Skype. It uses port 80 unless you tell it not to. Whatever it is, find it and fix it. At the moment you're only generating more problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify a port in a hosts file or DNS A record. You need to do one of two things:

1. Type :8080 into the browser at the end of your URL.
2. Redirect traffic on port 80 to 8080 using a reverse proxy, rewrite rule, or firewall rule.